# Ubuntu, how to see what directory was installed by what package

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu-16.04, dpkg

All, thanks for any help I am more of a Redhat distribution user and new job is all about Ubuntu, I am trying to figure out what package installed a specific directory. Namely under the `/var/lib/rancid/` path there is a `var` directory its full path is `/var/lib/rancid/var`. I am not sure I can install `apt-file` onto this server.

I have tried `dpkg --listfiles rancid` and `dpkg -S /var/lib/rancid/var *`.

Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: Should be "dpkg -S /var/lib/rancid/var", no?  Or search for one of the files in that folder.

Answer (score 2):

It is not in the list of files installed by the package (see https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/rancid/filelist ) but based on its name (`var`) I would suspect it is just created and used by the software at runtime.

Start by having a look at its configuration, maybe you will find something related.

Also, what problem do you have with this specific path? What prompted you to look after it?

Comment: Well the problem was related to a salt configuration under a pillar. The host wasn't defined in the top.sls. Thats what prompted me to look into the error. As far as the fix it was adding it into the top.sls under that respective pillar. The var directory under the parent of /var/lib/rancid/ was created by a script ran under that pillar definition